# How to uncheck mat checkbox in angular 14

Tags: typescript, angular-material2, angular-material-7, angular14

Trying to recheck the mat checkbox but not working. in my application after clicking the "Select Checkbox Car and Bus" button click on the input box and check the Bus and Car then click the cancel button of Bus and Car. again click the input field, now see the check boxes of Bus and Car unchecked but here checked. So In this condition how to uncheck the check boxes.

mauto.component.ts:

```
  removeChip = (data: any | ItemData): void => { 
    this.toggleSelection(data); 
  };

 
  toggleSelection = (data: ItemData): void => {
    data.selected = !data.selected; 
    if (data.selected === true) { 
      if (!this.selectData.find(({ item }) => item === data.item)) {
        this.selectData.push(data); 
      }  
    } else {
      const i = this.selectData.findIndex(value => value.item === data.item);
      this.selectData.splice(i, 1);
    } 
    this.selectControl.setValue(this.selectData);
    this.emitAdjustedData();
   };
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gzubna?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the chips and checkboxes in sync. So, when a chip is removed by clicking cancel, it should also uncheck the item, which should resolve the issue you are having.

```
toggleSelection = (data: ItemData): void => {
    data.selected = !data.selected;
  ​
    if (data.selected === true) {
      this.selectData.push(data);
    } else {
      let i = this.selectData.findIndex(value => value.item === data.item);
      this.selectData.splice(i, 1);
      
      i = this.rawData.findIndex(x => x.item === data.item)
      this.rawData[i].selected = false;
    }

    this.selectControl.setValue(this.selectData);
    this.emitAdjustedData();
  };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ay4et9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.html)

Comment: Filter option is not working, Because you removed filteredData. <mat-option *ngFor="let data of filteredData".

Comment: Please add filter option also

Comment: Sorry, I am not here to code the whole thing for you. I have noted in your previous question that filter was not correctly implemented in your code with rest of the things. You need to give it a try yourself, or open a question with full details how the filter is suppose to work, alongside chips, checkboxes and buttons.

Comment: The question you posted is not related to filter, as you commented here. Also, please upvote and accept above answer, if it resolved the issue in your question here.

Comment: I have resolved that filter issue

Comment: This is new SO : 73192946

Comment: I think you can answer it.

Comment: I am waiting for your answer